# Where we configure the credential in PutHDFS processor in Apache NiFi

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform, apache-nifi

I have configured a path in PutHDFS its throwing an authentication error

LOG:

2017-03-03 01:52:29,200 DEBUG [IPC Client (1496249304) connection to dnn01.com/10.4.151.88:8020 from root] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client IPC Client (1496249304) connection to dnn01.com/10.4.151.88:8020 from root got value #39976 2017-03-03 01:52:29,201 TRACE [Timer-Driven Process Thread-7] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine 105: Exception <- dnn01.com/10.4.151.88:8020: create {org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException): Permission denied: user=root, access=WRITE, inode="/raw/externaltbls/falcon/testing/.1PUGETSLA_PO810.P0125.EDIINV.P20150125.107.20160304025143629.gz":hdfs:hdfs:drwxrwxr-x at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:319) at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:292)

2017-03-03 01:52:29,201 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-7] o.apache.nifi.processors.hadoop.PutHDFS PutHDFS[id=015a1010-9c64-1ed3-c39b-d19ab2dfe19b] Failed to write to HDFS due to org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: IOException thrown from PutHDFS[id=015a1010-9c64-1ed3-c39b-d19ab2dfe19b]: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=root, access=WRITE, inode="/raw/externaltbls/falcon/testing/.1PUGETSLA_PO810.P0125.EDIINV.P20150125.107.20160304025143629.gz":hdfs:hdfs:drwxrwxr-x at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:319) at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:292)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PutHDFS processor is going to execute as the OS user that NiFi is running as. In your case it looks like you are running NiFi as root because the log says "Permission denied: user=root, access=WRITE".

Your options are:

1. Give root WRITE access to the directory you are writing to (/raw/externaltbls/falcon/testing/)
2. Run NiFi as a different user who has WRITE access
3. Use Kerberos and specify the principal and keytab in the PutHDFS processor

Comment: Thanks Bryan, it was helpful

Comment: How would you actually run nifi as a different user who has write access? Option 2

Comment: You have to be logged in as that user when you start NiFi